# Using AWS SDK: Streaming Audio from OVH Cloud S3 in a Nest.js REST API

Tags: amazon-s3, audio, nestjs

**Problem**
My problem involves building a REST API using Nest.js to fetch audio files from OVH Cloud's S3 storage. I want to achieve this without downloading the entire audio file but instead stream it to the client, which will be using Python to consume the data. I'm looking for guidance on how to implement this streaming functionality efficiently.

**Example Implementation:**
The main concept is that the API   will be consumed by a python resource , and this resource will be made of several scripts and a main method that will take the audio file as input and will give back a json file as output. The json file is going to contain several fields , and they are actually the real final result of the analysis.

```
import soundfile as sf
import numpy as np
import json

def get_average_loudness(audio_wav_file):
    audio_wave, _ = sf.read(audio_wav_file) 
    loudness = np.sqrt(np.square(audio_wave).mean()) 
    json_dictionary = {'average_loudness': loudness}  
    json_file = json.dumps(json_dinctionary           
    return json_file
```